# python equivalent of quote in lisp

Tags: python, functional-programming, lisp, quote

In python what is the equivalent of the quote operator? I am finding the need to delay evaluation. For example, suppose in the following lisp psuedocode I have:

```
a = '(func, 'g)
g = something
(eval a)
```

What I am doing is deferring evaluation of `g` till a later time. This is necessary because I want to define `g` later. What is the equivalent idea of this psuedocode in python?

Comment: Usually, if you're trying to translate something to Python, and it isn't obvious how to do so, you're doing something deeply unpythonic, and need to step back a level to find the Pythonic way to do what you're actually trying to do. In particular, any code that uses `eval` probably shouldn't be written in the first place.

Comment: I definitely will be trying to switch to clojure in the next few days...

Comment: To be honest, even in Lisp, `eval` is _not_ the correct way to delay the evaluation of an expression. Generally, you wrap the expression in a `lambda` and call it later on. Scheme also offers `delay`/`force`, which provides memoisation of the `lambda`'s result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
a = lambda: func(g)
g = something
a()
```

This isn't quite the most literal translation - the most literal translation would use a string and `eval` - but it's probably the best fit. Quoting probably isn't what you wanted in Lisp anyway; you probably wanted to `delay` something or create a `lambda`. Note that `func` and `g` are closure variables in the `lambda` function, rather than symbols, so if you call `a` from an environment with different bindings for `func` or `g`, it'll still use the variables from `a`'s environment of definition.

Comment: +1 As I mentioned to the OP, even in Lisp, `eval` is the wrong answer to most questions, including delayed evaluation. (EDIT: You just made an edit to say the same thing. :-D)

Comment: Note that python also has promise/delay libraries.

Answer (score 4):

Using `eval` for delaying evaluation is bad, both in Lisp and Python.

in Python, and in Lisp, you can delay evaluation using a closure:

```
def print_it(x):
    def f():
        print g(x)
    return f

f = print_it(42)

def g(x):
   return x * x

f()
```

Please note that what is captured in a closure is not the **value** of a variable, but the variable itself and this is sometimes surprising:

```
fa = []

for x in range(10):
    def g():
        print x
    fa.append(g)

for f in fa:
    f() # all of them will print 9

x = 42

fa[0]() # the output will be 42
```

to solve this problem (that can also be present in Common Lisp) you may see things like:

```
for x in range(10):
    def g(x = x):
        print x
    fa.append(g)
```

or (in CL) things like

```
(let ((a a))
  (lambda () (print a)))
```

Python also has a `lambda` special form for anonymous functions, but they are limited to one single expression and cannot contain any statement. A locally `def`-ined function instead is a regular function without any limitations.

```
for x in range(10):
    # print is a statement in Python 2.x and cannot be in a lambda
    fa.append(lambda x=x: sys.stdout.write(str(x) + "\n"))
```

Finally Python 2.x has a syntax limitation and closed-over variables are read-only because if there is an assignment (or augmented-assignment) in a function there are only two possibilities:

1. The variable is a global (and has been previously declared so with `global x`)
2. The variable is a local

and in particular it's ruled out that a variable being assigned could be a local of an enclosing function scope.

Python 3.x removed this limitation by providing a new possible declaration `nonlocal x` and now the famous `adder` example can be implemented as

```
def adder(x):
    def f(y):
        nonlocal x
        x += y
        return x
    return f
```